# Push to harbor registry using http

Tags: docker, docker-registry, harbor

I have installed Harbor registry without SSL certificate.
I tried these commands to push example docker image:

```
root@jenkins:/opt# docker tag hello-world:latest 211.70.171.219/library/hello-world:latest
root@jenkins:/opt# docker push 211.70.171.219/library/hello-world:latest
The push refers to repository [211.70.171.219/library/hello-world]
Get "https://211.70.171.219/v2/": dial tcp 211.70.171.219:443: connect: no route to host
root@jenkins:/opt#
```

Do you know is it possible to push an image or pull an image using http protocol?

Comment: VTC because this doesn't appear to be about programming. "no route to host" is a connectivity or configuration error. The IP address it is trying to route to is not the same as the IP you tried to push the image to, so either you have configured a proxy for that IP, or Harbor is redirecting to that IP.

Comment: I did a typo mistake.